# External JS calls

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have the following code:

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.JSTestJs1}" 
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"/>

        <lightning:button label="Click me - I dare you" 
        onclick="{!c.buttonClickEvent}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    afterScriptsLoaded: function(component, event, helper){},
    buttonClickEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        helloWorld('controller');
        helper.helloWorld();
        helper.sayHi('Alex');
    }
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    sayHi : function(name) {
        alert('Hi ' + name);
    },
    helloWorld : function()
    {
        helloWorld('helper');
    }
})
```

And this is the external JS file:

```
function helloWorld(source) {
    alert('Called from ' + source);
}
```

But when I run the app, I receive the following error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "export" the function in your include file in order for it to be accessible:

```
window.helloWorld = function(source) {
  alert('Called from '+ source);
}
```

This window is a SecureWindow that is limited to your own component, so it won't leak the function into other components.

Comment: Not sure that I understand the reason for [window.]. So now I want to export a class:
`"user strict";

export default class MyJs {
    function helloWorld(source) { 
  alert('Called from ' + source);
 }
}`
When calling it using: MyJs.helloWorld('controller');I get the following error:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:JSTest$controller$buttonClickEvent [MyJs is not defined]
Failing descriptor: {c:JSTest$controller$buttonClickEvent}

Going back to the window portion, adding it as a prefix to the method, it still does not work.

Comment: Even if you don't understand it, try it and see if it works. If you need additional clarification as to why you can ask a question for more specific information.